Are there any issues in hoisting a reducer dispatch out of component?
I realize this is quite the a-typical use case, but I've ran into a situation in which I need to be able to call the dispatcher from outside the component tree. I understand the typical suggestion would be to avoid this entirely, but unfortunately I cannot, hence, this setup.
My code looks like this:
function reducer(state, action) {
    // ...
    console.log('reducer', state, action);
    return action.v;
}

let d;
export function dispatch(v) {
    d.call(this, { v });
}

function App() {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, { v: 20 });
    d = dispatch;
    return <h1>{state.v}</h1>;
}

Example use, in another module:
import { dispatch } from '...';

setInterval(() => {
    dispatch({ v: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000) });
}, 2500);

From what I can tell, there doesn't seem to be any actual issue with this approach, beyond the obvious limitation that the dispatcher can only be called once the component is set up (which is very workable). Using it like this seems to keep the past state in tact and causes rerenders as desired. Is there anything I'm missing? Any reason why this would cause issues?
